# Invalid Project Path on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am using the 2019 version of Unity with Mac Build Support. When I try and create a new project I get an error saying that the project path is invalid or the project path does not exist. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the unity hub and editor but it didn't change anything. I have tried saving to many folders on my mac but none are working.

Comment: What have you set your working directory to be?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Long shot but it might be that your path has a special character. I used to have build problems with Unity because of it.  Make sure your path has only English characters.

Answer (score 7):

For others who face this issue, in Unity Hub, you need to select the folder that contains the "Assets" and "Library" folders of your project. If your Unity project does not have those folders, even creating empty subfolders will let you open the project in Unity.

Also, make sure your path holds only English characters.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with project creation and path. When I changed to the root like C://Unity/ it worked perfectly.

Special characters could cause some problems, try using only English characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working for now by downloading unity 2018 which worked. It must be a bug in 2019 or something. Eventually I'll try to fix it so I can use 2019.